# CSS alignment support

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
p.submit {
text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p class="submit">
  <input type="submit"value="submit" name="SUBMIT"/>
</p>
```

I'm trying to align my Submit button to center, but it doesn't work.

Comment: use `margin:auto;`on the input

Comment: Can you show some more code? What is not working?

Comment: Seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/QjjNr/

Comment: Like Musa said, it already works.

Comment: This works fine. Something you're not showing us might not be.

Comment: I don't know why, but it doesn't work.....

Comment: I'm really confused...

Comment: @Fred - are you applying `display: block` to input? This would cause `text-align` to not be applied to the submit button.

Comment: p.submit {magin: auto; text-align: center; display: block; }

Comment: That's what I did so far...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `margin:auto` on the `input`, it will center the element. It makes the margins on both sides of the element always the same. But since `input` is an inline element, you have to also use `display:block`, because you can't adjust the margins on inline elements

```
input {
  margin:auto;
  display:block
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V3Qp9/)

Also, your example works for me in Firefox 22

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V3Qp9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

This will target the submit button within the p element, centering it.

```
p.submit input[type='submit'] {
   margin: auto;
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: This won't target anything. The `p` element has a class of submit, not the input

Comment: The HTML code was added afterwards, my answer has been updated.

Comment: My mistake and yes I have.

Comment: That's better :) A little more complex than probably needed, but it still works